# NextJS v13 stylesheet order leads to preventing css not being applied

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am currently migrating my project to NextJS v13 and mostly use SCSS combined with Tailwind. It looks like NextJS that NextJS creating these two separate stylesheet files.

1. layout.css
2. page.css

and the order of them is like this

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/src/app/(root)/layout.css?ts=1667467308870" data-precedence="high">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/src/app/(root)/page.css?ts=1667467308871" data-precedence="high">
</head>
```

Now my `layout.tsx` looks like this (the order of my impors, especially my .scss is really important):

```
'use client';
import '../../styles/app.scss';
import {Layout} from '@app/components/layout.component';
```

So if I want to change the border of my Card Component the styling of my Card is higher prioritized than the Tailwind, even when I add it after my card className.

```
<Card className={clsx(post.book ? 'border-orange-300' : '')}>
...
```

[image: Styles]

but if I change my order like this (can change the order by changing the import order in my `layout.tsx`):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/src/app/(root)/page.css?ts=1667467308871" data-precedence="high">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/src/app/(root)/layout.css?ts=1667467308870" data-precedence="high">
</head>
```

the Tailwind border is being applied, but Tailwind is gonna replace my custom Input styling because of this order. I'm using PostCSS for Tailwind.

Anyone have a idea how I can fix this issue? I don't really want to use `!important` and before migrating to NextJS v13 it was working & the import order in my `layout.tsx` wasn't important back then.

Comment: My bad. I thought I can the the HTML order by changing the import order in my file. It doesn't work. My general stylesheet must be at the top...